# Prove that $P[a \leq X \leq b] = F_X(b) - F_X(a^-)$ if $a \leq b$

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I want to prove the following:

Let $X$ be a random variable and let us denote with $F_X$ the distribution function. By $a^-$ we denote the left-limit.

**Claim**:

$P[a \leq X \leq b] = F_X(b) - F_X(a^-)$ if $a \leq b$ and

$P[a < X <b] = F_X(b^-)- F_X(a)$ if $a < b$

Deduce that:

$P[X=b] = F_X(b)- F_X(b^-)$.

**Attempt**:

To compute: $P[a \leq X \leq b]$ I can use the fact that - given the density function $p$ (can I assume there exists one?) - we have:

$P[a \leq X \leq b] = \int_a^b p(x) dx$.

Now:

$\int_a^b p(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^bp(x) - \int_{-\infty}^ap(x)  = F_X(b) -F_X(a) .$

Why do I need to consider the left limit and why not just write $F_X(a)$ instead? For the first as well as the second point in the claim I get the same result but without considering the left-limit. I don't see where this is necessary.

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**

Without assuming that there is a density function:

$P[a \leq X \leq b] = P[X \leq b] - P [X < a] = F_X(b) - F_X(a^-)$

and for the second point

$P[a < x < b] = P[X < b] - P[X \leq a] = F_X(b^-) - F_X(a)$

Comment: I don't think you should assume there is a density function. $X$ might be any random variable, not necessary continuous. Specifically in the case where $X$ is continuous this is indeed $F_X(b)-F_X(a)$. But not in the general case.

Comment: The way the question was asked suggests that you are not allowed to assume that the random variable is absolutely continuous, meaning that it might not have a PDF.  $F_X(a)=F_X(a^-)+P(X=a)$, but I'm not sure if you can use that, or are supposed to show that. Is this a problem for a class or from a book, and if so, is that equation in your notes or the book?

Comment: @Joe This is an exercise our professor left us to solve. But from the comment Mark made, I assume that I'm not allowed to assume that there exists a density function.

Comment: I tried the following: $P[a \leq X \leq b] = P[X \leq b] - P[X < a] = F_X(b) - F_X(a)$. Since $X$ is strictly less than $a$ I assume that I need to consider the left-limit? Could it be that? Then: $P[X \leq b] - P[X < a] = F_X(b) - F_X(a^-)$

Comment: @Mark I've made an edit. Does it work that way?

Comment: @MyGanton Yes, now it's fine, assuming you know why $\mathbb{P}(X<a)=F_X(a^-)$ indeed holds. (these are just properties of probability)

Comment: @Mark The answer from Aryaman Maithani made it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Letting $F_X = F$.)
Try showing the following general fact: $$F(a^-) = P[X < a].$$ Everything else follows from that.

---

To show the above, note that given any increasing sequence $a_n \uparrow a$ (with $a_n < a$ for all $n$), we have
$$\{X < a\} = \bigcup_{n \ge 1}\left\{X \le a_n\right\}.$$
Note that the union on the right is an increasing union. Thus, by continuity of probability, you get
$$P[X < a] = \lim_{n \to \infty}P\left[X \le a_n\right] = \lim_{n \to \infty} F(a_n).$$
Can you finish it now?

Comment: Since $a_n < a$ and $a_n \uparrow a$ it seems for me that $lim_{n \to \infty} F(a_n)$ is just a representation of the left-limit. Is that enough to argue that $ lim_{n \to \infty} F(a_n) = F(a^-) $ or is there a specific argument to take the limit inside of $F$?

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what I had in mind. Note that I had used an arbitrary $(a_n)$. So, what I showed is that given _any_ $a_n \uparrow a$, we have that $\lim_n F(a_n)$ exists and equals $P[X < a]$. Thus, I have shown that $F(a^-)$ **exists** _and_ **equals** $P[X < a]$. $${}$$ In fact, one can show that $F$ is an increasing function (this is very direct). As a result, it follows that $F(a^-)$ does exist and I could've chosen any $(a_n)$ of my choice, for example, $a_n = a - 1/n$. (So basically in my second paragraph, I only check what $F(a^-)$ equals, having the guarantee of existence.)

Comment: To deduce that $P[X=b] = F_X(b) - F_X(b^-)$ I tried the following: $P[a \leq X \leq b] - P[a < X < b] = F_X(b) - F_X(a^-) - F_X(b^-) + F_X(a)$. I assume that $F_X(a^-)$ and $F_X(a)$ cancel out each other. But why is that not the case with $F_X(b)$ and $F_X(b^-)$?

Comment: @MyGanton: No, $F(a^-)$ and $F(a)$ do not cancel in general. In fact, $$P[a \le X \le b] - P[a < X < b] = P[X = a \text{ or } X = b].$$ The thing you want is $$P[X = b] = P[X \le b] - P[X < b].$$ (In terms of notations of intervals: $$[a, b] \setminus (a, b) = \{a, b\}; \quad (-\infty, b] \setminus (-\infty, b) = \{b\}.$$

Comment: I see my mistake, thanks!